# What's the probability that Johnny cheated?

Tags: probability

> Johnny has not studied for tomorrow's test, so his probability of
>   passing it is only 1/4. However, if he cheats, he will raise his probability of passing
>   to 3/4. He hasn't yet decided whether or not to cheat, but he is leaning that way:
>   the probability that he will cheat is 3/4. Suppose he takes the test and passes it.
>   What is the probability that he cheated?

**My attempt**
[image]

Is my solution correct?

Comment: This looks good to me!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your solution is quite correct.

But (unless you are in a hurry in the middle of a test) you should not be afraid of using complete English sentences when writing it down.  Mathematical language is meant to *complement*, not to substitute the spoken language. You should also delete portions you never use, in this case "P(fail honestly)=3/4".  Finally, you should stick to a uniform notation, either "P(pass | honestly)=1/4, P(pass | cheating)=3/4" or "P(pass honestly)=1/4, P(pass by cheating)", but not shift from one to another.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.